# Reverse Proxy (NGinx) with captcha

Tags: nginx, reverse-proxy, brute-force-attacks

I am trying to prevent some brute force attacks on an web app by having a captcha before the login page.

The application itself is not modifiable by me, so I cannot change the login form.

I could put something like Authelia in front of the web app, but this would be total overkill. I don't need 2FA, just a simple captcha will do.

I read some entries here and on the web about testcookie-nginx-module but this seems to be very old and not really maintained. Also, I would have to compile the module and include it into NGinx, what I try to avoid.
Some other posts are 8-14 years old...
I was not able to find an up-to-date post or project.

I am looking for some project (docker based would be ideal) and include it as a 3rd party app to my setup (just like Authelia).

It is hard to believe that there is no such project. Does anyone know something? Preferable open-source.

Thank you,
schube

Comment: CAN you use JWT for instance if captcha is correct?

Comment: Hi! I don't really understand the question. I GUESS some captcha service would place a cookie and then in NGinx I would check if the cookie exists. If yes, fine, if not, redirect to the captcha service. At least, that is how I think it would work. I don't know how a JWT would help here. The point is, I cannot modify the existing webapp, so I only have the tools NGinx provides. (The existing webapp uses JWT btw.) Thank you!